# What is Fedora's equivalent of 'apt-get purge'?

Tags: fedora, yum, apt, package-management

In Debian, there's at least two ways to delete a package:

- `apt-get remove pkgname`
- `apt-get purge pkgname`

The first preserves system-wide config files (i.e. those found in "**/etc**"), while the second doesn't.

What is Fedora's equivalent of the second form, `purge`? Or maybe I should rather ask if `yum remove pkgname` actually preserves config files.

Answer (score 30):

`yum remove` is not guaranteed to preserve configuration files.

As stated in the [yum HOWTO](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/yum_HOWTO/yum_HOWTO/yum_HOWTO-10.html):

> In any event, the command syntax for package removal is:
>
> ```
> # yum remove package1 [package2 package3...]
> ```
>
> As noted above, it removes package1 and all packages in the dependency tree that depend on package1, **possibly irreversibly as far as configuration data is concerned**.

**Update**

As James points out, you can use the `rpm -e` command to erase a package but save backup copies of any configuration files that have changed.

For more information, see [Using RPM to Erase Packages](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-erase.html). In particular:

> It checks to see if any of the package's config files have been modified. If so, it saves copies of them.

Comment: That's not really true, "rpm -e" will remove the configuration files _if_ they haven't changed. If they have been changed they are moved to <filename>.rpmsave and not deleted.

Answer (score 10):

I found this answer to a duplicate question on ServerFault titled: [yum equivalent of “apt-get purge"](https://serverfault.com/questions/41502/yum-equivalent-of-apt-get-purge) that provides the only method I've seen that can do what `apt-get purge <pkg>` does on Ubuntu/Debian.

```
for package in package1 package2 package3
do
  echo "removing config files for $package"
  for file in $(rpm -q --configfiles $package)
  do
    echo "  removing $file"
    rm -f $file
  done
  rpm -e $package
done
```

The only other method I can conceive of here is to parse the output from `yum remove <pkg>` and then manually delete any files that may have been modified. For example when I recently installed ElasticSearch's RPM for 2.3 I modified several files that were associated with this RPM. When I removed it with YUM you'll get messages in the output like this:

```
warning: /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch saved as /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch.rpmsave
warning: /etc/elasticsearch/logging.yml saved as /etc/elasticsearch/logging.yml.rpmsave
warning: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml saved as /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml.rpmsave
```

These can be deleted post removal using YUM either scripted or by hand.

#### Reference

- https://serverfault.com/a/41519/2518

Comment: This might be an interesting dnf plugin....

Comment: @mattdm - this issue has come up from time to time, would be nice if we could do this in the "RPM" world.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent for "purge", just use `yum remove package`.

Also you can use `yum reinstall package`, when you want to reinstall some package...

Comment: Actually, as explained in [Justin Ethier's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/what-is-fedoras-equivalent-of-apt-get-purge/8193#8193), `yum remove` is equivalent to `apt-get purge`.

Comment: @Gilles Justin Ethier says `yum remove` is "*not guaranteed* to preserve configuration files." That's not the same as saying that it is *guaranteed not* to preserve configuration files (which would mean it is equivalent to `apt-get purge`). Are you making this (much) stronger claim?

Comment: @EliahKagan That's the way I understand the yum howto that Justin cites. I'm not sure that it's right, the [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-managing-packages.html#sn-yum-removing-software) seems to be saying the opposite.

Comment: I think it's undefined behavior. Yum may or may not preserve configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

For Fedora 31:

Uninstall:

```
sudo dnf remove PACKAGE
```

Clean caches and other not needed files (not this is not the same as purge as far as I understood it)

```
sudo dnf clean all
```

To get more information about the command (before you execute the above):

```
dnf clean
```

This does nothing but show you the help screen for the clean command. Read also the manual, sometimes they are worth the time.

```
man dnf
```

For first time man users:

- press / to start searching
- type clean, press return
- press n until you are in the section
- note: In this case you could also just search for Clean Command but without knowing anything about the manual this would be not so easy.

See also:

- /etc/dnf/dnf.conf -> setting clean_requirements_on_remove for a setting related to the asked operations
- see `man dnf.conf`

  > clean_requirements_on_remove boolean
  >
  > Remove dependencies that are no longer used during dnf remove. A package only qualifies for removal via clean_requirements_on_remove if
  >   it was installed through DNF but not on explicit user request, i.e. 
  >   it was pulled in as a dependency. The default is True. 
  >   (installonlypkgs are never automatically removed.)
- https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html

Answer (score -2):

If you want to clean up config files from a program that you recently removed via an RPM system, all you have to do is enter: yum clean all

Comment: This is incorrect. The "yum clean all" merely cleans up cached metadata, mirror lists, etc., used by yum. It does nothing to configuration files.